# What is the Pythonic way of handling classes, modules, and packages with the same name?

Tags: python

I have some code with what looks like silly name-spacing. Here is a stripped down example:

```
/genelist
    genelist.py
        - class GeneList
    helper1.py
    helper2.py
    ...
```

`GeneList` is the only symbol I'd like to use throughout my program. That class delegates to other utility functions inside the package. The problem is that sometimes I need to reference the class like this:

`gl = genelist.genelist.GeneList()`

That seems silly. Is there a more Pythonic way to organize my code (or name my components) to reduce the boilerplate?

EDIT: I need to name space for [circular imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you use `/genelist/__init__.py` in your genelist module(folder)

```
from genelist import GeneList
```

then in whatever.py

```
import genelist
genelist.GeneList()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import the class using `from genelist.genelist import GeneList`, and reference the class only as GeneList, for example: `g1 = Genelist()`

Comment: Right, but I need to namespace for [circular imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python).

Comment: circular imports are usually a red flag that you should refactor your code

Comment: Let's assume they aren't in this case.

Comment: but the part of the problem is the circular imports :P ... the right thing to do is fix it .... the sorta ok thing to do is come up with import hacks to allow it ...

Comment: Fair enough. I'll reinvestigate and see if the issue is avoidable.